# Bash - print lines of textfile in random order

Tags: bash, text-processing

How could I print the lines of a `text-file` in random order on the command-line?

is there a tool like `cat` or `tac` that can do this?

Comment: shuf? https://linux.die.net/man/1/shuf

Comment: @Theophrastus, nice and easy :-) This is my answer! Love <3

Comment: In the dupe question, replace `seq 100` with `cat filename`.  Or just use `shuf filename`.